# Number of components of Levi Civita Connection $\Gamma^a_{bc}$.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, projective-geometry, connections

How follows on page $1$ of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0801.0300.pdf) paper, in the second last paragraph, the three formulas containing $n$, namely

> $n^2(n+1)/2$
>
> $n+n(n+1)/2$

and

> $n(n^2-3)/2$

Maybe it will suffice for me to understand the first number $n^2(n+1)/2$  to get the rest:

This is the number of independent components in $\Gamma^a_{bc}=\Gamma^a_{cb} $, but I do not understand the combinatorics behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its enough to get the first, namely the number of components of a Levi-Civita connection is 
$$
\frac{n^2(n+1)}{2}.
$$
To get this just note that $\Gamma^a_{bc}$ is collection of triple $\{a,b,c\}$ where $a,b,c=1,2,\dots,n$, with symmetry condition in the last two indices, that is $\Gamma^a_{bc} = \Gamma^a_{cb}$.

To calculate this, note that there are $n^3$ possible configurations of triple of all possible value of them. Because the last two indices is symmetric we cannot count them twice. So we need to exclude half of the **combination** of $\{a,b,c\}$ with $b \neq c$. For a fix $a$ there are $2 \times n(n-1)/2$ possible combination of $\{a,b,c\}$ with $b \neq c$.

To see this we can represent $\{b,c\}$ for all value $b,c$ as matrix, then this number is the number of elements of the upper and lower triangular part minus the diagonal which is 
$$
2 \times \frac{n(n-1)}{2}.
$$
Because we want to exclude half of them, just devide by two. There are $n$ number of $a$ (that we fixed before), therefore the total components of $\Gamma^a_{bc}$ is 
$$
n^3-n \frac{n(n-1)}{2} = \frac{n^2(n+1)}{2}
$$

$\textbf{Note} :$

Its good to folow this with simple case $n=3$. All the $\Gamma^1_{bc}$ components are
\begin{align}
& \Gamma^1_{11} \quad \Gamma^1_{12} \quad \Gamma^1_{13} \\
& \Gamma^1_{21} \quad \Gamma^1_{22} \quad \Gamma^1_{23} \\
& \Gamma^1_{31} \quad \Gamma^1_{32} \quad \Gamma^1_{33} 
\end{align}
We want count $\Gamma^1_{12}$, $\Gamma^1_{13}$, etc once so just substract $n^2$ with the upper diagonal $n(n+1)/2$. So we have $n(n-1)/2$ components of $\Gamma^1_{bc}$ that we want to eliminate. For all $a$'s, there are $n \times n(n-1)/2$. Therefore the all components that left is $n^3-n\times n(n-1)/2= \frac{n^2(n+1)}{2}$.

Comment: How does it follow $b\neq c$ from $\Gamma^a_{bc} = \Gamma^a_{cb}$?

Comment: Its fixed now. You can try to follow with simple case like $n=2$ or $3$.

Comment: I think you're great, I believe it now. Thank you