# A surrounding manifold for the connection involved is missing.

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, connections

In [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0801.0300.pdf)
paper, in the very first paragraph, we have the notion of projective equivalence of connections $\Gamma$ and $\hat{\Gamma}$ but we **do not have**
a manifold $M$ for these connections, only an open set $U$!

Comment: Every open subset of Euclidean space **is** a manifold.

Comment: Its called open submanifold.

Comment: @Sou燈馬想 Coould you please have a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2541445/projective-structure-smooth-manifolds-and-the-degrees-of-freedom ? Thank you